# why cannot del a dictionary in python 3?

Tags: python

I created a dict in python 3, its type is dict as expected,

```
dict = {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
type(dict)
```

then I deleted it with `del`, but it still exists and type is changed to "type"

```
del dict       # delete entire dictionary
type(dict)
```

Why does del not work on the dict? Why is type changed?

Comment: Don't call your dictionary `dict`. This is a reserved name for a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), which you overwrite with your script.

Comment: It's exactly like @MrT says. Change the name and all will work as expected.

Comment: `del dict` removes the global (assuming you've defined it as such) name, exposing the shadowed builtin. Don't use names of builtins, as noted by others.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to "abuse" the word **"*dict* "** in your scripts then you can use the word **"*dict* "** only like this **"*dict_*"** by using **"*_* "** behind it.

[>> Here <<](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) is pythons build-in list of words reserved for your scripts functionality by python.

In semantics context:

The word **"*reserved*"** means **"*to keep or set apart for some particular use or purpose in its functional/semantic context.*"**.

Thus if your change those reserved words your script/code/program comes tumbling down like a house of cards and python starts spitting **"traceback errors"** when you run your code. Regardless of your free choice to change the wording of them into other lingo, you have to correct **all** those words written in your scripts/code to maintain its functionality in place by these "reserved" words. If not you have a bright "debugging" future ahead for all you scripts where you changed these "reserved" python wordings/ built-in functions.

Comment: Those aren't actually reserved words, as the OP's problem demonstrates; built-in functions and classes are *provided*, but not *reserved*. Python provides them, but you're allowed to use them for your own variable names, it's just a terrible, terrible idea. The keyword list is available from [`keyword.kwlist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.kwlist), and [the language spec also describes both keywords and reserved names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.kwlist).

Comment: Totally agree with you ShadowRanger.

Answer (score 0):

When you name your dictionary `dict` there is a problem.

`dict` is a built-in function.

Rename the dictionary and try again:

```
dict1 = {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
type(dict1)
del dict1
dict1
```